# Concat strings in Azure without XML

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have a query where I am trying to join distinct values from two rows. I am using Azure SQL DW and it does not support XML functions.

This is the query I have written:

```
SELECT CAST(STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + cast(s.MONTH_ID AS VARCHAR(6))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MONTH_ID AS VARCHAR(6)) AS MONTH_ID
        FROM dbo.MARGIN_CLASS_FACT
        ) s
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS VARCHAR(35)) AS MONTH_ID;
```

When i am using FOR XML PATH
I am getting this error
** Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 1, column: 212: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.**

the input is:

```
2018
2019
```

The result output should be like this:

```
201808,201809
```

Comment: The Stuff / FOR XML code is a traditional hack around Sql Server's lack of MySql's GROUP_CONCAT feature. Although Sql Server itself now finally has STRING_AGG, this isn't yet supported on Azure DWH as per the Duplicate link.

Answer (score 1):

**The below is Azure SQL 12.0.2000.8, but obviously doesn't work on Azure DWH**

The [`Stuff / Xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30045441) hack to work around the lack of MySql's GROUP_CONCAT / Oracle's LIST_AGG is no longer needed in recent versions of Sql - we now have [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) versions 2017 and later:

```
select STRING_AGG(MyColumn, ',')
from [dbo].[MyTable];
```

I've just checked this on an recent Azure DB

> Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Aug 31 2018 20:17:59
>   Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: it is showing a STRING_AGG is not a built in function

Comment: I just ran a query with STRING_AGG against a SQL Azure database, and it worked fine. Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Aug 31 2018 20:17:59   Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: My Bad - the OP has listed Azure DWH. Likely not updated yet with `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: @StuartLC: How do I proceed as you have marked it as a duplicate

Comment: That's pretty much it - there is no answer, as Azure DW neither supports most of the XML (or JSON) functionality needed to do your STUFF / XML hack, and neither does it support the 'proper' STRING_AGG feature that MS finally implemented in the mainstream SQL (incl Azure) database. There's a feature request for [this here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/14876763-stuff-for-xml). You might try [these other workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings) too.