# LINQ ICollection of a Model to a string with Name and Surname from within another model

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a field which is a collection of a model ICollection "Parties", which is in another model "Matter". I want to extract the Name and Surname of each party and separate with a "/" using LINQ. I am putting these into a field called Investors, the second last item.

This is my query:

```
    var matterQuery = (from matter in context.Matters
  select new
  {
      matter.ID,
      matter.AttorneyRef,
      matter.Status,
      matter.ProductType,
      matter.IsDiscarded,
      matter.Base_CreatedDate,
      matter.Base_CreatedBy,
      matter.BranchID,
      matter.InstitutionID,
      matter.InvestmentTypeID,

      StatusName = matter.MatterStatu != null ? matter.MatterStatu.Name : string.Empty,
      ProductTypeName = matter.ProductType1 != null ? matter.ProductType1.Name : string.Empty,
      AccountNumber = matter.Account != null ? matter.Account.AccountNumber : string.Empty,
      CreatedBy = matter.Paralegal != null ? matter.Paralegal 
      : matter.AspNetUser != null ? matter.AspNetUser.FirstName + " " + matter.AspNetUser.LastName
      : matter.User != null ? matter.User.Firstname + " " + matter.User.Surname
      : string.Empty,
      IntermediaryName = matter.IntermediaryBranch != null ? matter.IntermediaryBranch.Intermediary.Name 
      : matter.Attorney != null ? matter.Attorney.AttorneyName
      : string.Empty,
      CloseRequested = matter.CloseAccounts.Where(x => x.Status == (int)CloseAccountStatusEnum.Authorised).Count() > 0,
      StatementRequested = matter.Account != null ? matter.Account.StatementRequested : false,
      RequestedDate = matter.RequestedDate.HasValue ? matter.RequestedDate.Value : matter.Base_CreatedDate,
      Investors = matter.Parties.Select(x => x.Name.ToString()).Concat(matter.Parties.Select(x => x.Surname.ToString())),
      SoftLock = matter.SoftLock,
  })
   .AsQueryable();
```

I need this in 1 long string as I am doing a search on the results for a filter and the following line:

```
(x.Investors != null && x.Investors.ToLower().Contains(search))
```

requires it be in a string format. I want to display the results as "Name1 Surname1 / Name2 Surname2 / ..."

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I have tried Join and Aggregate but I get the errors:

base {System.SystemException} = {System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
   at System.Da...

and...

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String])'

Comment: What's the output type of  your search? IQueryable? IEnumerable?

Comment: The matterQuery is IQueryable. I do a seach on it later using linq's Where so that remains an IQueryable. The Investors field I am trying to get is currently an IEnumerable<string>

Comment: You can add AsEnumerable() which would make the result into an IEnumerable, thus you can use string.Join().

Comment: BTW you don't need to write like that. You could write like: StatusName = matter.MatterStatu.Name ?? "" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by:

In the original query:

```
select new{
Investors = matter.Parties.Select(x => x.Name + " " + x.Surname), 
}
```

In the search:

```
matterQuery.Where(x =>
(x.Investors.Any(y => y.ToLower().Contains(searchString)))
);
```

When transferring data to a ViewModel:

```
Investors = String.Join(" / ", matter.InvestorNames),
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your search is working and the result of the search is `IEnumerable<string>`, you can do this to create the string that you want:

```
// IEnumerable<string> searchResult = ... this is your search statement
string result = String.Join(" / ", searchResult);
```

Comment: The search is done after the initial query, thats why I need 1 long string from the query before I search to be able to use ToLower(). See my edit for when I try use a join

Comment: You can't use the String.Join inside the LINQ query, because your LINQ query will be translated into a SQL query and the engine is not able to create the SQL equivalent of the String.Join. Basically, you cannot use C# statements inside LINQ query. That means you have yo get the query result (as IEnumerable), then convert it to array and use String.Join

Comment: It won't allow me. I tried Join and Join<> and I get the error :   "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join(string, params object[])' and 'string.Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>)'"

Comment: I changed the statement. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sparrow, I understand a lot more now ;) I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand your problem right, you have two options:

1. Bring all results from database and do the join locally
2. Call a sp to do that

Check this [Is there a "for xml path" equivalent in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990748/is-there-a-for-xml-path-equivalent-in-linq-to-sql)